# python assign value to pandas df if falls between range of dates in another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the best way to create a new column and assign a value if date falls between two dates in another dataframe ?

e.g.

```
dataframe A    
date          values
2017-05-16      x  
2017-04-12      Y


dataframe B    #df contains dates to use to filter and associated id

start            end           id
2017-05-08     2017-05-18      34
2017-04-24     2017-05-08      33
2017-04-03     2017-04-24      32
```

desired result

```
dataframe A     
date          values    id
2017-05-16      x       34 
2017-04-12      Y       32
```

I have looked into pd.cut which doesn't seem to work for what I want and it seems inefficient to write a loop to iterate over the dataframe with multiple conditions.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself but for similar problems [intervaltree package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intervaltree) was suggested.

Comment: What about the dates falling on the edges such as "2017-04-24"? Which ID should be picked?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using an `IntervalIndex`, which is new in Pandas 0.20.0.  This looks to still be in the experimental phase though, so other solutions may be more reliable.

```
# Get the 'id' column indexed by the 'start'/'end' intervals.
s = pd.Series(df_b['id'].values, pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_b['start'], df_b['end']))

# Map based on the date of df_a.
df_a['id'] = df_a['date'].map(s)
```

The resulting output:

```
        date values  id
0 2017-05-16      x  34
1 2017-04-12      Y  32
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind altering the index of `df_b`, you could just directly convert to an `IntervalIndex` on it:

```
# Create an IntervalIndex on df_b.
df_b = df_b.set_index(['start', 'end'])
df_b.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(df_b.index)

# Map based on the date of df_a.
df_a['id'] = df_a['date'].map(df_b['id'])
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of something that's really straightforward to do in one step in sql, but not so much in Pandas. So with the proviso that I don't love this approach, here it is.

1. do a full cartesian join
2. filter down to desired rows & columns.

_

```
# First Full Outer Join Dataframes 
# (Requires a Common Column in Pandas Unlike SQL)
df_A['fake key'] = 1
df_B['fake key'] = 1
outer_join = pd.merge(df_A, df_B, how='outer', on='fake key')

# Now Filter Back down to Desired Rows/Columns
desired_rows    = outer_join.query('date < end and date > start')
desired_columns = ['date', 'values', 'id']

final = desired_rows[desired_columns]
final
```

output:

```
        date values  id
0 2017-05-16      x  34
5 2017-04-12      y  32
```

The things that make this answer somewhat unsatisfying to me are:

1. The first step of a full cartesian join doesn't scale well at all to large data
2. The cartesian join requires a common column, so in this case first creating that fake key column (see [this github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5401)